# ERROR:_radians Referenced From

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, cgpoint

It might be duplicate . But what my problem is i added the **CGPointUtils.c/.h** into my project . I got the error in the **.h** file . error is `"_radiansToDegree" referenced from` like  `CGRect referenced from`error message.

I checked the  code everything in it is correct, CGFloat data types it returns radiansToDegree(rads). This is where i got the error.

code:

```
CGFloat angleBetweenPoints(CGPoint first, CGPoint second) {
CGFloat height = second.y - first.y;
CGFloat width = first.x - second.x;
CGFloat rads = atan(height/width);
return radiansToDegrees(rads);
```

In the last line, where the error is?
Could any one give me a solution for that.
Thanks

Comment: BTW, if `first.x` is the same as `second.x` you will crash with a divide by zero error.

Comment: No. They are different so no error like that. Mine is with the _radianToDegree_

Comment: And they will _always_ be different? It is best to check for that case and special handle it. Yeah, I know that is not your question, that is why I wrote a comment.

Comment: You're not giving us much to go by here.  Is the error a link error? Is it complaining that radiansToDegrees is not defined or multiply defined? Where is radiansToDegrees declared? (and have you #imported that file?)

Comment: @DRVic. yeah it's type of link error. I Declared the *math.h* so it comes under math function. But the eror is *"radiansToDegree"referenced from*. What it indicates & what can i do now?

Answer (score 0):

radiansToDegrees isn't in math.h.

Probably the simplest solution is to write one, (it's just a multiply by 180/M_PI).

Comment: Thank You @DRVic I Got it Forgot some header files to include for Degree functions. Shame on me